# I want Exif Information of image in C++/MFC ? (Use xnview.dll)

Tags: c++, mfc, exif

I am new to C++/MFC development and trying to get metadata of image (Exif Information). I used xnview DLL also but I am not getting proper solution can anyone help me out?

Comment: See if [this](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) suits you.

Comment: *"I am not getting proper solution"* is not very helpful. What are you getting? What are you expecting? Using what code? As it's currently written, this question is off-topic for stackoverflow. Please see [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MFC doesn't provide Exif information features. However, you can use GDI+, within your MFC application. Refer: [Reading Metadata from a File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533832(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: If you find the answer acceptable, kindly Accept it. If you find any other question or answer, you should up-vote it. This keeps everyone encouraged and helps people to help you. This is how SO community works! :)